# I want to use preg_replace to replace string with an array of identical patterns but different replacements

Tags: php

I want to replace different patterns in a string with the identical string.
The replacements is an array with different values.

Since the pattern has to be mixed, I cannot find a solution. Also because `preg_replace_all` doesn't exist. Does anybody have an idea?

My code:

```
$artikelinhoud = $simpleXml->StandaardOplossing->attributes()->ArtikelInhoud;
$arrayImages = array();
preg_match_all('<!\[(CDATA)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\]>', $artikelinhoud, $arrayImages);

$images = array(); 
foreach ($arrayImages[2] as $key => $image) {
$images[$key] = 'src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . $image . '"';   
}

$imagesOld = array();
$imagesOld[] = '/type="(.*?)"/';

$artikelinhoud = preg_replace($imagesOld, $images , $artikelinhoud);
```

So variable `$imagesold` is always the same. And `$images` is an array with different values to put between  tags.

Comment: `preg_replace` replaces already **all** occurances of the pattern. But propably you're interested in [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: yes, but why it replaces all the patterns with $images[0] and not with $images[0], $images[1], etc?

Comment: Because with `preg_replace()` you're very limited in replacement of the matched string. But use `preg_replace_callback()` to have more possibillities.

Comment: I'd like to post the code, but I need to see an example of what `$images` looks like. Does it contain `$1` that substitutes something for the capture group un `$imagesOld`?

Comment: images is array( [0]=> string(26464) "src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AA........) ,[1]=> string(22464) "src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AA........)            it is meant to put between the <IGM> tag in HTML             It needs to replace different times <IMG type="jpg">  So different images replace same patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I found [this solution](http://mikefenwick.com/blog/using-php-preg_replace-to-replace-one-string-pattern-with-an-array-of-replacements/) perfect for me.

In your code:

```
$artikelinhoud = $simpleXml->StandaardOplossing->attributes()->ArtikelInhoud;
$arrayImages = array();
preg_match_all('<!\[(CDATA)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\]>', $artikelinhoud, $arrayImages);

$images = array(); 
foreach ($arrayImages[2] as $key => $image) {
  $images[$key] = 'src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . $image . '"';   
}

$imagesOld = array_fill(0, count($images), '/type="(.*?)"/');

$artikelinhoud = preg_replace($imagesOld, $images , $artikelinhoud, 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: i already found a solution with DOM xpath, but thanks anyway!